# Conveyor animation for Powerpoint presentation

Tags: animation

I need to create a powerpoint slide showing an animated 3D model of a conveyor belt.
Just like this without the wheels inside...

[image]

I wanted to use a cube as the conveyor belt, which I expand to multiple segments using the array modifier.

[image]

All segments should then move along a curved path.

Unfortunately, I come to the end of my abilities when trying to implement this animation in Blender.
I think I am losing my mind :)

My approach so far has been the following:

Creat the path:

- Draw a circle and stretch it to an oval
- Convert the circle to curve

Create the conveyor segments

- Add a cube and resize it (the mesh should be the conveyor belt)
- Add Modifier Array to Mesh
- Enter the number of segments
- Add Modifier Curve

That's it.
If I now select the conveyor belt and move it in Y direction, all segments move along the path.

The tricky part is to get the whole thing to work as an animation in Powerpoint.
As far as I know, animations in Blender have to be equipped with an armature, so that the animation works in Powerpoint.

- Therefore I inserted an armature.
- Then I select the cube and the armature and press CTRL - P (with Automatic Weights).
- If I now move the armature in Y direction, the conveyor belt still runs along the path.
- After inserting the keyframes for the armature I export the file.

But the segments of the conveyor do not move along the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help and best regards
Michael :)

Comment: Hi Michael, looks like the inserting of you images didn't work. The easiest way to insert an image to your question is: edit your question, move cursor where you want the image to be and then just paste it in there. (CTRL-V)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: I have never exported animations to Office products, but as far as I know your assumption of armature requirements is correct. However despite there being an armature in your scene your animation is still based on a curve modifier that bends the shape, and that can't be exported. You will likely need an armature only based animation

Comment: just a dumb question: why can't you just import the animation in office as a movie file?

Comment: Thank you guys so much!
I will try the suggested solution. Seems like it will work for me!

Thx a lot @ all!